# Deleted %WINDIR%

Tags: windows, environment-variables

I was messing around on Windows 10, deleted the `%WINDIR%` system environment variable, and rebooted my computer. Now, many things are broken, including the elevation prompt and the System Properties panel. How can I restore the variable?

Comment: "How can I restore the variable?" - Edit the system variable and restore the value.  If you cannot do this in Safe Mode, then you are likely in a situation where an in-place reinstall will be required.  In the future, DO NOT delete default system variables.

Comment: open a normal command prompt and type `setx windir "%SYSTEMROOT%"` then reboot.

Comment: Can you go here and do a Repair Install?   https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you can open Regedit:

1. Go to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment`.
2. Right-click the values list, select *New → Expandable String Value*, enter `windir` as the name and `%SystemRoot%` as the value.

If you can still open Command Prompt:

1. `reg add "HKLM\SYSTEM\CurrentControlSet\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v windir /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^%SystemRoot^%`

Otherwise:

1. Boot into a Windows install USB.
2. Press Shift+F10 to open Command Prompt.
3. Run `regedit`.
4. Select the `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` branch.
5. Choose *File → Load Hive…* and open the `Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM` file from your main system disk (not the install USB one). Enter a temporary name, e.g. `temp`.
6. Under `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE` open the newly loaded `temp` key (with the name you gave), and descend to `ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment`.
7. Right-click the values list, select *New → Expandable String Value*, enter `windir` as the name and `%SystemRoot%` as the value.
8. Go back up to `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\temp` and select *File → Unload Hive*.
9. Close Registry Editor.
10. Run `wpeutil reboot`.

Alternative steps:

3. Run `reg load HKLM\temp C:\Windows\System32\config\SYSTEM`
4. Run `reg add "HKLM\temp\ControlSet001\Control\Session Manager\Environment" /v windir /t REG_EXPAND_SZ /d ^%SystemRoot^%`
5. Run `reg unload HKLM\temp`.
6. Run `wpeutil reboot`.

Comment: easier method:  from a command prompt (does not have to be elevated) `setx windir "%SYSTEMROOT%"`

Comment: I fixed it in a similar way. Luckily, I had a USB drive loaded with Ubuntu live lying around (I couldn't make Windows media because that would require admin) and was able to follow steps 5-7 using [`reged`](https://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/bionic/man8/reged.8.html).

Answer (score 2):

You still can use a normal command prompt because that will open in `%USERPROFILE%` rather
than `%WINDIR%\System32`.

In the command prompt, enter the following command

```
setx windir "%SYSTEMROOT%"
```

This command restores the WINDIR variable you deleted.

Now reboot your computer and everything is back to normal.

If for whatever reason your SYSTEMROOT parameter is not correct, but you know the location of your windows folder, for example C:\WINDOWS, you can also type `setx windir "C:\WINDOWS"`

Comment: This didn't fix the elevation prompt for me.

Comment: You did reboot first, then tested, right? The reboot is essential. If not, ensure that you also have SYSTEMROOT set to C:\WINDOWS. So type `setx SYSTEMROOT "C:\WINDOWS"` and reboot.

Comment: That did not help for me either. I suspect WINDIR needs to be a system variable.

Comment: setx sets systemvariables. set is used for user variables. That's why a setx will not be present until you close and reopen the command prompt, but given that you have more serious issues, a reboot is actually necessary. But you may have removed more than just %windir%. To test that it is present now, open a command prompt and type `set` if it worked, windir is now present there. Also check systemroot

Comment: [`setx` sets user variables by default.](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows-server/administration/windows-commands/setx#:~:text=The%20default%20setting%20is%20the%20local%20environment.) It probably needs admin to set system variables.

Comment: Ah, good point. If you deleted it from the system variables rather than the user, as I thought you were doing, its going to be really hard to fix this. I would try to enable the administrator user, then login with that, and start command prompt normally, then do the setx command. Another option you can try is creating a script that does the setx command, then use scheduled tasks to run the script and use as user NT AUTHORITY\SYSTEM (just select other users, type system and press search) and run that. That may still work.

Comment: you can also try win+r, then type in `cmd /s /k pushd c:\ ` and press ctrl-shift-enter to run as administrator in c:\

Comment: I managed to fix the problem, but running that command now, it creates an elevation prompt.